# Two team playoff question, homework help

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am working through my college text book (mathmatical statistics freund/walpole) trying to refresh my stat skills. Its been a couple years...
I would sure appreciate any pointers on an exercise question that has me stumped...

**In a two -team playoff in some sport, the winner is the first team to win m games.**

**(a) Counting separately the number of play offs requiring m,m +1,....,  2m-1 games, show that the  toatl number of different outcomes (sequences of wins and losses) is 
$$
2\left[ {{m-1}\choose {m-1}}  +  {{m}\choose {m-1}} +   ... + {{2m-1}\choose{m-1}}\right]
$$
(end of question)**

I drew this out as a path problem, wins along the X and wins losses along the Y. By inspection I can see that one team can win a best of 5 (m=3) in the following ways 
Team A has to win 3 games, but they can only loose 2 in the process...

$$
\left[ {{3}\choose {3}}  +  {{4}\choose {3}} +  {{5}\choose{3}}\right]
$$

The other team might win the series as well, so I would need to multiply the above by 2.

I can generalize this to

$$
2\left[ {{m}\choose {m}}  +  {{m+1}\choose {m}} +   ... + {{2m-1}\choose{m}}\right]
$$

I have tried various substitutions but I can not seem to get to the form asked for. 
I notice they are using (m-1) in the bottom. For my working scenario, this would equate to

$$
2\left[ {{2}\choose {2}}  +  {{3}\choose {2}} + {{4}\choose {2}} + {{5}\choose{2}}\right]
$$

This only makes sense to me in the case of a full series, or a sweep since 
$$
{{5}\choose{3}} = {{5}\choose{2}}   and   {{3}\choose{3}} = {{2}\choose{2}} 
$$

Are they counting the ways for Team B to loose?

Any tips or pointers? I am sure I am missing something fundamental.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The given answer seems strange to me - it has (m+1) terms though it says it is considering separately m possibilities, and it disagrees (at least for m=3) with your answer which is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: What I said here is incorrect: as the answer below says, we've both counted, for example, AAABB as a five-game series when in fact it would end after three games and we've counted it there as AAA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think the proposed answer that the question provides is correct.

Let's enumerate the cases.  Let $A$ and $B$ be wins for each team.

Then, for $m=3$:

Series that end in three games:  $AAA$, $BBB$.

Series that end in four games:  $AABA, ABAA, BAAA, BBAB, BABB, ABBB$.

Series that end in five games:  $AABBA, AABBB, ABABA, ABABB, ABBAA, ABBAB, BBAAB, BBAAA, BABAB, BABAA, BAABB, BAABA$.

This is consistent with the following formula:

$$
2\left[ {{m-1}\choose {m-1}}  +  {{m}\choose {m-1}} +   ... + {{2m-2}\choose{m-1}}\right].
$$

If we look at your best-of-five case, the series which end in three games had two wins by one of the teams.  This is different than saying that the series *will* end in three games if one of the teams wins the first two.

In other words, when counting the series that end in less than $2m-1$ games, one only needs to consider the combinations of wins and losses for the games *prior to* the series-ending game.

This is consistent with the formula originally proposed in the problem, but it goes one too far.  I think it should stop at ${{4}\choose {2}}$ rather than ${{5}\choose{2}}$.

Comment: John. Thanks for the input. Following your logic, why is your first term  ${{m-1}\choose{m-1}}$ and not ${{m}\choose{m}}$. <br> It looks to me like you have 3 choices and are specifying all of them.  Similar question holds for the second term...  (im really confused here...)

Comment: your answer works out for case m=4 as well. Oddly enough, the answer by your method, for both m=3 and m=4 gives the same permutation count as  $2{{2m-1}\choose{m}}$. Which, by brute force, seems to be the right answer.  my head hurts.

Answer (score 0):

For the play-off requiring $m$ games, the number of possible sequences of wins is given by:
$$n_m={m\choose{m}}={{m-1}\choose{m-1}}$$
For the play-off requiring $m+1$ games, the number of possible sequences of wins is given by:
$$n_{m+1}={{m+1}\choose{m}}={{m}\choose{m}}+{{m}\choose{m-1}}={{m-1}\choose{m-1}}+{{m}\choose{m-1}}$$
...

For the play-off requiring $2m-1$ games, the number of possible sequences of wins is given by:
$$n_{2m-1}={{2m-1}\choose{m}}={{2m-2}\choose{m}}+{{2m-2}\choose{m-1}}\\=\left[{{m-1}\choose{m-1}}+{{m}\choose{m-1}}+...+{{2m-3}\choose{m-1}}\right]+{{2m-2}\choose{m-1}}$$

Using the same argument you used, we consider the possible sequences of losses (the other team wins) and that gives:
$$n_{Total}=2\left[{{m-1}\choose{m-1}}+{{m}\choose{m-1}}+...+{{2m-2}\choose{m-1}} \right]$$